# SSH command for looping through directories EXCEPT a few specified

Tags: bash, loops, ssh

Would it be possible to execute a bash command via SSH which loops over multiple directories EXCEPT 3 or 4 that I specify? Something like:

Delete `public_html/outdated/` for all directories in `/home/` except `/home/exception1/` , `/home/exception2/` and `/home/exception3/`

I am on a HostGator Dedicated Linux server.

Comment: You probably don't intend to have an initial slash on `public_html/outdated/`

Comment: You're right, thank you @Dennis Williamson I corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test first!

```
shopt -s extglob
rm -rf /home/!(exception1|exception2|exception3)/public_html/outdated/
```

Comment: this is gorgeous and straightforward. I'm not sure if you need to repeat the `home` directory in the list of exceptions though. At least it didn't work for me until I changed it to just     `(exception1|exception2|exception3)`.

Comment: ALSO I needed to execute `shopt -s extglob` to get the `!` operator to work, but it works great now.

Comment: Sorry, I was just copying and pasting from your question without thinking. Also, sorry I forgot to mention `extglob`. I'll correct my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is all one line, but I've split it here for readability

```
find /home
    \( -wholename '/home/exception1'
    -o -wholename '/home/exception2'
    -o -wholename '/home/exception3' \)
    -prune -o
  -wholename '*/public_html/outdated' -type d
  -exec rm -rvf \{} \;
```

**Before running this I strongly suggest replacing the `-exec rm -rvf \{} \;` bit with `-print` to verify that it prints only what you want deleted.**

Here's how it works: `find` recursively finds stuff. the stuff in `\(`...`\)' matches directories you want to skip entirely (ie: prune). The standard pattern for using`-prune`is to say what you want to prune out, then`-prune -o`, and then the stuff you actually want to match.

We want to match `public_html/outdated` directories, so that's what `-wholename '*/public_html/outdated' -type d` is for. (`-type d` means "is a directory").

Finally comes the action we want to perform. Once again, replace this part with `-print` until you're sure it does what you want.

One caveat: This will spit out a bunch of warnings of the form:

```
find: `/home/foo/public_html/outdated': No such file or directory
```

This is because find is trying to walk into those directories it just deleted. You can safely ignore these -- find will continue despite the warnings.

Comment: You can try using `-execdir` instead of `-exec` along with `-depth` to see if that eliminates the error messages.

Comment: @Dennis I hadn't tried execdir, but I did play around with `-depth` thinking that it might solve the problem (as we'd be done with a subtree by the time we deleted it). This seemed to completely break the pruning, however, so I abandoned that approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution - there's probably better ways to do this.

```
cd /home
ls */public_html/outdated
```

will should you all of those; you can use grep -v to remove lines from that

```
ls */public_html/outdated | grep -Ev ^exception1/ | grep -Ev ^exception2/ | grep -Ev ^exception3/
```

and then use backticks to feed these into `rm -rf`

```
rm -rf `ls */public_html/outdated | grep -Ev ^exception1/ | grep -Ev ^exception2/ | grep -Ev ^exception3/`
```

Obviously you should run the middle step to verify the list before you actually delete them!

Note that this may not work if any of your directories have spaces in - although usernames in /home shouldn't. The safe way to do that is using `find`. (There's probably a way to do the exclusion with find but I can never remember.)